# Cannot use SQL in Python twice

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, insert

I want to add(insert) data twice or more times without turn off the program. But there is a mistake. I guess that I should make a loop but don't know how. Please help me:

```
from tkinter import *
import pypyodbc
import ctypes

#Create connection
con = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;PageTimeout=5;MaxScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL={MS Access};DriverId=25;DefaultDir=C:/Users/HP/Desktop/PITL;DBQ=C:/Users/HP/Desktop/PITL/PITL.mdb;')
cursor = con.cursor ()

form=Tk ()
form.title ("Add data")
form.geometry ('400x200')

a = Entry (form, width=10, font="Arial 16")
a.pack()
b = Entry (form, width=10, font="Arial 16")
b.pack()

def Add ():
    cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO Laws (`Law_name`, `Fine`) VALUES (?, ?)", (a.get(), b.get()))
    con.commit ()
    cursor.close ()
    con.close ()

Button=Button(form, text = 'PUSH ME', command = Add)
Button.pack()

form.mainloop ()
```

It is a mistake when I insert data second time

> ```
> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File
> "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",
> line 1699, in __call__
>     return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\PITL\ADD DATA.py", line 20, in Add
>     cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO Laws (`Law_name`, `Fine`) VALUES (?, ?)", (a.get(), b.get()))   File
> "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.4-py3.6.egg\pypyodbc.py",
> line 1470, in execute
>     self._free_stmt(SQL_CLOSE)   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.4-py3.6.egg\pypyodbc.py",
> line 1987, in _free_stmt
>     raise ProgrammingError('HY000','Attempt to use a closed connection.') pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('HY000', 'Attempt to use a
> closed connection.')
> ```

Comment: Your code is explicitly closing the connection, so of course you're going to get this error. Either open a connection right before you need it, or don't close the only connection you have.

Comment: Well you are `cursor.close ()`ing in the first iteration inside the function. Just take it out, put it after `Button()`. Or use a while loop, which will be unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: For future reference formatting the error as code helps readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call the close methods only after finishing all your queries. Try commenting the lines where you do

```
cursor.close ()
con.close ()
```

Once you finished all your changes (your main loop maybe?), then close the cursor and the connection

Comment: Oo, thank you! Before I put these lines after button (befor mainloop), but it didn't work. Then I just put it at the end and it works